# Write jax-ws web service and generate WSDL without XSD

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, wsdl, jax-ws

I wrote a simple JAX-WS web service for tomcat application server on java.

I have one interface and on implementation class:

*interface*

```
@WebService(name = "myWs")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface IMyWs {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getUser")
    Response getUser(@WebParam(name = "phone", mode = Mode.IN) String phone);

}
```

*implementation*

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ge.mari.IMyWs")
public class MyWs implements IMyWs {
    @Override
    public Response getUser(String phone) {
               // SOME CODE
        return response;
    }
}
```

**My problem is that, in my wsdl file Response class is defined in xsd file.** 

This is the snippet from my wsdl file

```
<types>
<xsd:schema>
          <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.mari.ge/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/MyServcie/MyWs?xsd=1">
</xsd:import>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
```

**How can I make web service to generate all types in WSDL file instead of separate XSD file?**

Should I change any configuration or add some annotation to my web service?

Answer (score 12):

You can have JAX-WS insert the generated schema into your WSDL file by using the

```
-inlineSchemas
```

command line switch. [1]

If you're using Maven in your project you can configure the JAX-WS maven plugin to do the same with the **inlineSchemas** configuration element in your execution configuration as follows: [2]

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>SomeId</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsgen</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <sei>some.class.Name</sei>
        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
        <keep>true</keep>
        <resourceDestDir>some/target/dir</resourceDestDir>
        <inlineSchemas>true</inlineSchemas>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

No changes to your Java class are necessary.

[1] http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/wsgen.html

[2] http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsgen-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it ist not possible to have JAX generate a WSDL with schemas inline.

BTW: Separating the WSDL definition and the XSD schema is a good move (you might want to use the object structure defined by the schema in a different context e.g. storing data to files or something like that).

That said: If you **need** an "all in one" WSDL (because some ancient client requires it) you can always have `jax-ws` generate the WSDL initially and then edit it to your heart's content. The edited WSDL can be included using the `wsdlLocation` parameter of the `@WebService` annotation.

Comment: It indeed is possible to instruct JAX-WS to inline the schema. See my answer above for how instructions on how to achieve that.

Comment: @Kallja: I assumed the OP was referring to the WSDL generated by the application server (because there is a `schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/MyServcie/MyWs?xsd=1"` in the WSDL-fragment. I don't know of a way to convince an app server to generate an all-in-one WSDL... **BUT** your point is a good one. I need to remember the `wsgen` param you used. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually **not** possible to use `inlineSchemas` with the runtime WSDL generator. I debugged the WSDL generation and found this line in the `EndpointFactory`, where the `inlineSchemas` feature (which actually *is* present in the `wsgen` tool) is just set to `false`:

```
    /**
     * Generates the WSDL and XML Schema for the endpoint if necessary
     * It generates WSDL only for SOAP1.1, and for XSOAP1.2 bindings
     */
    private static SDDocumentImpl generateWSDL(WSBinding binding, AbstractSEIModelImpl seiModel, Collection<SDDocumentImpl> docs,
                                               Container container, Class implType) {
        // [...]
        WSDLGenInfo wsdlGenInfo = new WSDLGenInfo(); 
        // [...]
        wsdlGenInfo.setInlineSchemas(false);
        // [...]
        seiModel.getDatabinding().generateWSDL(wsdlGenInfo);
        // [...]
    }
```

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/blob/f37dae6bdfd03bafdad63ed05b27dbfc3c38af1b/jaxws-ri/rt/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/ws/server/EndpointFactory.java#L658

There is also an open issue for JAX-WS to change this (but I guess there is not much hope for changes in JAX-WS anymore).
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/issues/49