# Inline schema in wsdl with Jaxws

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

How to generate the WSDL in one document instead of having a schema import in the wsdl  with jaxws ?

```
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://test/1.0" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/test/1.0?xsd=1" /> 
</xsd:schema>
```

I want to remove that and inculde the schema even in my wsdl as one file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAX-WS has XSD schema in different URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030574/jax-ws-has-xsd-schema-in-different-url)

Comment: Duplicate of [Write jax-ws web service and generate WSDL without XSD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399718/write-jax-ws-web-service-and-generate-wsdl-without-xsd)

Comment: here is another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934477/90101